# Android Studio Links Projects Which Include Same Local Library

Tags: android, android-studio

Within Android Studio I have a Library Project (SDK) and 2 projects which implement the SDK (Project 1 and Project 2).

In each of the 2 projects' `settings.gradle` I am softlinking to the library project:

```
include ':theSdk'  
project(':theSdk').projectDir = new File('../path/to/sdk/libraryModule')
```

The problem is that when I open Project 1 and build, and then open Project 2 and build I see Project 1 linked inside Project 2.  There are no other references between the 2 projects, other than they each have the SDK softlinked to them.

Within Project 1 I see Project 2 listed as a module in the Project Settings modal, as well as being listed as a module in the Project window.

Has anyone else run into this, and if so how do I prevent my projects from muddying each other up?

Thanks

Comment: Why this line `project(':theSdk').projectDir...` ?

Comment: I have seen this issue as well. One thing you can do is to name the local project differently, like `local-theSDK` when using it as a local dependency, so that when you can still open up that dependency project separately if you like. You can't keep the local project from showing up in your parent project though.

Comment: @giddy-naya that is to pull in the project locally.  I believe it's a soft link.